# Python, get the redirected URL of the passed in one with requests lib

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I have the following URL, that if opened, after a few seconds redirects to a new URL which automatically redirects to another one.

I want to get the third one.

yet, after redirecting the first one, if I manually open it, it redirects me to the third and desired one.

but if I'm trying to this with requests in python I get the response code and not the URL.

```py
def get_redirected():
    with_token_url = requests.get(SPOTIFY_USER_ACCESS, timeout=10, allow_redirects=True)
    redirected_url = with_token_url.url
    print(redirected_url)
    end_url = requests.get(redirected_url, timeout=10)
    print(end_url.url)
```

output:

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/login?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.spotify.com%2Fauthorize%3Fscope%3Duser-read-private%2Buser-read-email%26response_type%3Dtoken%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252F0.0.0.0%253A7000%252F%26state%3D123%26client_id%3Dc13f9174976545dc88adabebe21d7e56
https://accounts.spotify.com/login?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.spotify.com%2Fauthorize%3Fscope%3Duser-read-private%2Buser-read-email%26response_type%3Dtoken%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252F0.0.0.0%253A7000%252F%26state%3D123%26client_id%3Dc13f9174976545dc88adabebe21d7e56
# Which is the indeed the second and redirecting link.

# or if I'm using end_url instead end_url.url in The last print
<Response [200]>
```

The last URL shoul look something like this:

```
http://0.0.0.0:7000/#access_token=BQAKrMh1kftqXxoU9mNDPp2131231Obq5xwIss3Idj3fZZj17s7C3UIGALfy-EPn8uZLjqN5OksNjlR3BpuHZOk3jwTJcloWcuqNjRc-l8JY6d2c0ZKnTpXrMg5DThViQdWzMlRb1WhsB_6uWwzkfHioEpN6kk2Q5mqB3iKfuxBZnI132313123kEAhTVaGI8CQ&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&state=123
```

I need this url so I can strip the access token from it.

Comment: allow redirects in the end_url as well

Comment: it results in the same output